# Path based routing between two static websites S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have two different react applications in two separate buckets (app1, app2). I would like to route my traffic like this:

- www.example.com -> app1 (hosted in bucket app1)
- www.example.com/app2 -> app2 (hosted in bucket app2)

I tried to use Cloudfront with two Origins and two Behaviors but looks like www.example.com/app2 doesn't work as expected. It's looking for a folder "app2" in my bucket app2, and will not redirect my traffic to my index.html. I just want to route my traffic on different static website according to the path. Any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cloudfront can't strip down portions of the path (app2 in your case). See AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginPath).
One option would be to put your app2 files in a folder named app2, this way the app2 behavior will find them.

Another option is to use CloudFront lambda function to rewrite the URL.

Comment: The first option doesn't work because if I put a folder app2 inside my bucket app2, when I try to access to www.example.com/app2 I have a 404. But if I try www.example.com/app2/index.html, I can see correctly the index.html (but not the react app, just the static html file)